# Can I give my own custom link to some categories in wp - ecommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am using Mazine template [demo](http://Mazine.transparentideas.com) which is using wp-ecommerce plugin,  In my website I have setup left Categories and Brands widgets, What I need is to link some of categories/Brands to link to my own custom URLs instead of opening category page.
Can I do that? Which specific file I need to change to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last got the solution,

Just Edit wpsc-category_widget.php file under Mazine folder , and added some conditions to change the link of some of categories.

```
     <?php if($ti_curr_cat['name']=="Category Name"){ ?>

                <a href="<?php echo "http://my_custom-Link.com" ?>"><?php echo $ti_curr_cat['name']; ?></a>

                <?php }else{?>
                <a href="<?php echo $ti_link; ?>"><?php echo $ti_curr_cat['name']; ?></a>
     <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using http://ecommerceshoppingcart4u.com to build an ecommerce site. It only involves a one off payment which is very cheap. The price is £267